# Is there a specific Gatling configuration to avoid "SSL Handshake timed out" exception?

Tags: ssl, https, gatling, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

I'm using Gatling for overload tests and I'm having a lot of errors when I use the HTTPS urls of my platform.

I get :

- 27% of `j.n.s.SSLException: handshake timed out`
- 23% of `j.n.c.ClosedChannelException`
- 17% of `j.n.s.SSLException: failure when writing TLS control frames`.

When I call the same platform without HTTPS (in HTTP so), the same simulation is 100% OK.

We are trying to understand why there are these errors and have tried some configurations:

- Use `.shareConnections` option in `httpProtocol` definition
- Define `sslEnabledProtocols` and `sslEnabledCipherSuites` into gatling.conf. All others `ahc` configurations are commented :

```
sslEnabledProtocols = [TLSv1.2]
sslEnabledCipherSuites = [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
```

But no success... Same results...

Is there a chance that the problem is a Gatling configuration ? Or is it a platform configuration problem ?

For information, my simulation looks like that :

```scala
setUp(
    Scenario1.scn
      .inject(
        rampUsersPerSec(1) to 3 during 5 minutes,
        constantUsersPerSec(3) during 5 minutes
      )
      .protocols(httpProtocolSite1),

    Scenario2.scn
      .inject(
        rampUsersPerSec(1) to 3 during 5 minutes,
        constantUsersPerSec(3) during 5 minutes
      )
      .protocols(httpProtocolSite2),

    Scenario3.scn
      .inject(
        rampUsersPerSec(1) to 3 during 5 minutes,
        constantUsersPerSec(3) during 5 minutes
      )
      .protocols(httpProtocolSite3)
)
```

And my scenarii logic is to load a first html page, make a pause (2 minutes) and load a second html page.

Thank you for any information that could be useful on these issues !

Comment: Hi have you found the issue? My API should handle 2500req/s, and at about 150 i get same error as you do "j.n.s.SSLException: handshake timed out". What was the solution after all?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting your issue wrong: you're blaming the messenger (Gatling)!

Your system under load is simply unable to deal with the load you're throwing at it.

2 possibilities:

1. You've properly designed your load and it matches what you're trying to simulation. Then check your network (eg bandwidth) and the component in your architecture that's in charge of https/TLS (nginx, AWS ELB...). Check configuration and possibly consider scaling out (multiple endpoint with DNS round robin).
2. Your load design is broken. Eg, if you want to simulation server to server traffic, you should probably be using `shareConnections` (otherwise, don't use that, your test would be meaningless).

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

I'm in the first case, the simulation is well designed and the problem is elsewhere and I was wondering if the problem could be in Gatling configuration or on the VM that host Gatling or is it, exclusively, on the target ?

I want to simulate a user that navigate on a website : in that case the shareConnections is meaningless ? 

Thanks again for the help !

Comment: As I said: 1) Issue is exclusively in the application, not Gatling. 2) `shareConnections` is meaningless for  simulating web browsers traffic.

Comment: PS: your ops can't see such issues in their APM/monitoring because they can only monitor what happens behind the public endpoint. So don't accept any "everything's fine on our side" answer.

Comment: PPS: FrontLine has TCP and TLS metrics to give better insight on those failures.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this property value in cli like (gradle): -Dgatling.ssl.handshakeTimeout=20000
The same way you can ovewrite default values in gatling as per the docs:

https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/configuration/

The file with settings is under:

https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/main/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf